# Angular Auth Guard is not navigating to new Route

Tags: angular, auth-guard

My Auth Guard is working as intended in regards to attempting to search a URL without logging in. However, when signing in, the navigation in the URL does not change and the user is not routed to the correct page. It is*, however, running the correct sign in method to reroute to the intended page, so I'm not sure why it is not or if there's some sort of underlying rule I'm missing when using an Auth Guard. I am also using a lazy loaded home page, in case that has something to do with it...

My Auth Guard...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanLoad, Route, Router, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanLoad {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService, 
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean  {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn !== true) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/')
    }
    return true;
    
  }
  
}
```

My Sign In method. Notice the console.log() within it. It runs when using the Auth Guard, proving that it should work...

```
signIn(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.isLoggedIn$.next(true);
          console.log('Sign in method...');
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
        });
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
      }).catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message)
      })
  }
```

My Getter Method to return a boolean for the Auth Guard...

```
get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return (user !== null) ? true : false;
  }
```

My Lazy Loaded Routes...

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'home', 
      canLoad: [AuthGuard], 
      loadChildren: () => 
        import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
    }, 
    {
        path: 'onTheirWay', 
        canLoad: [AuthGuard], 
        loadChildren: () => 
            import('./on-their-way/on-their-way.module').then(m => m.OnTheirWayModule)
    }, 
    {
        path: 'preorders', 
        canLoad: [AuthGuard], 
        loadChildren: () => 
            import('./preorders/preorders.module').then(m => m.PreordersModule)
    }
  ];
```

**UPDATE**

I should also clarify. If I take away the Auth Guard in the Routes file, the sign in method navigates to the proper page as it should. It has something to do with the Auth Guard. Adding the code as shown above is affecting the navigation from running.

**UPDATE**

Here is my routes file for my Auth components which includes a "/" path...

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { SigninComponent } from './signin/signin.component';
import { SignoutComponent } from './signout/signout.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'signout', component: SignoutComponent }, 
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent }, 
  { path: '', component: SigninComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule { }
```

**UPDATE**

In the signIn method, I tried injecting a route:ActivatedRoute in the constructor and replacing the

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
```

with

```
this.router.navigate(['/home'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

It seems to work sometimes*, but other times it doesn't. So I'm not sure what's causing this. Anyone savvy with routing and its relationship with Auth Guard or know why this is happening?

Comment: Have you considered `pathMatch:'full'` on your empty route? See https://angular.io/api/router/Route#:~:text=id%27%2C%20component%3A%20Team%7D%60.-,The%20path-match,-strategy%20%27full%27%20matches

Comment: I actually just tried that right now, it didn't work. Same issue with the navigation.

Comment: In `AuthGuard` if you replace `this.router.navigateByUrl('/')` with a `console.log` does it get hit?

Comment: Also, why are you using `ngZone` here?

Comment: That console.log() does show if I replace that line. And, interestingly enough, it doesn't reload the signin component despite already staying at the correct URL. So it doesn't seem to want to load any component.

Comment: Admittingly, I'm trying out Authentication code that I found to help set up Firebase sign in. I tried omitting that ngZone and simply running the code inside of it, but same result.

Comment: If you navigate to `/home` manually does it work?

Comment: If I get passed the Auth Guard, it doesn't redirect me, but yes, I can navigate to /home directly. I looks like I'm starting to get a console error of "Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging" and the browser is crashing. So I'm wondering if that has something to do with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234888/discussion-between-aviad-p-and-acdev).

Answer (score 0):

Do a `return false` after your redirect.

```
 canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean  {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn !== true) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      return false; // <-----------------------
    }
    return true;
    
  }
```

Comment: No it still has the same issue. The sign in method in the service is running, but, it's not running the navigation code. I don't have any other navigation code anywhere else that would override it either. So not sure what could be stopping the reroute in that method.

Answer (score 0):

it is not line by line execution. Wrap return true into else block.

```
canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean  {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn !== true) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/')
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work either. Something is stopping the route navigation within the sign in method from running. The console.log() line right before it is running. I even tried adding a route navigate line right there in the Auth Guard return true block, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Do you really have a / route ? your const routes: Routes = [] doesn't have it. Either declare it or add a redirect from /

{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},

Comment: I have a "/" route that leads to my Sign In Component. I have updated my question above to show my auth-routes file. My app-routes and my auth-routes have worked well together up until I added the Auth Guard, so I'm not sure what exactly it's doing to interrupt the navigation.